# How to autopopulate MS Access fields with info from another table

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a food purchasing and inventory database for a restaurant. Originally, the invoice/ordering data was stored in Excel.

I created several tables in Access: "Vendors", "Invoices", and "Orderers" (we have several orderers that each handle certain vendors). I imported the list of orderers and vendors from the Excel spreadsheet into their own Access tables.

I then imported the rest of the data from Excel into the "Invoices" table in Access. The problem is that the "Vendor" field in Excel was just the name of the vendor as a text string (rather than a number). So for each of the records in the "Invoices" table, in the "Vendor" field, I have the name of the vendor instead of the vendor ID.

What I want to do is create a new field in the Invoices table called "Vendor ID" (which is linked to the Vendors table by a relationship), and then for each of the currently existing record in the Invoices table I want to autopopulate the Vendor ID field based on the text string that is currently in the "Vendor" field. (I will then remove the Vendor field from the Invoices table, once they have all been converted, and just have a Vendor ID for each invoice item)

So for instance, right now in the Invoices table I have something that looks like this:

```
Invoice ID  Invoice Date    Orderer ID  Price   Vendor  File Date   Vendor ID

27  5/29/2015   3   $85.00  Blue Heron Bakery   6/1/2015    
28  9/30/2014   5   $42.00  Calliope Farm   10/7/2014   
29  11/2/2014   5   $15.10  Calliope Farm   11/14/2014  
30  9/26/2014   2   $129.19 Cash and Carry  10/7/2014
```

And in my Vendors table, I have:

```
ID  Vendor Name
2   Blue Heron Bakery
3   Calliope Farm
4   Cash and Carry
```

So, for instance, for Invoice 27, since the Vendor field is currently "Blue Heron Bakery", I want to autopopulate the Vendor ID field by looking up the ID for Blue Heron Bakery in the Vendors table ... How do I do this?

Comment: I don't use Access, but one thing that you could consider is to Google "open source restaurant (management) software" - that should give you lots of ideas and may save you a lot of work?